# Many functions in pocketsphinx (like bin_mdef_free) not exported to lib on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, pocketsphinx

I am writing an simple phoneme forced alignment demo. I just copied some initialization code in the unit test file.

However, there are some functions causing LNK2019 error. Here is the list:

```
bin_mdef_free
dict_init
dict_free
dict2pid_build
dict2pid_free
ps_alignment_init
ps_alignment_free
```

I manually listed the symbols in pocketsphinx.lib, and I found many bin_mdef functions are listed, but except bin_mdef_free. (using DUMPBIN /ALL) All alignment functions are missed.

What should I do to include them in my lib file?

Answer (score 0):

This is just because pocketsphinx did not export these functions. One should add POCKETSPHINX_EXPORT macro to these functions and recompile the source code to lib file.